# MySQL's mediumint through jdbc

Tags: mysql, jdbc, types

If I query for a `mediumint` column from a MySQL table through jdbc, what type would I get back in the ResultSet object?

Or would that be an error?

(I know JDBC's Types.java doesn't have MEDIUMINT).

Comment: Im not familiar with JDBC but choosing INT and specifying its length to 5 would do the same wouldnt it?

Comment: I don't think so. MySQL's doc says "the width of the column is irrelevant to its value", maning, just because you set the width (or length as you put it) to '5', doesn't mean the number will be capped to `99999`

Answer (score 2):

You can use almost any Java Type (look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.0-en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html)) but the best way is to use Integer, since  `Short` would be to short for `MEDIUMINT` and to get back the result you should use the method `rs.getInteger("COLUMNNAME")`

Answer (score 0):

Not an error.  The column type as returned by [ResultSetMetaData.getColumnType()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnType%28int%29) is 4, INTEGER.  If you invoke ResultSet.getObject(), you'll get a java.lang.Integer.  Invoking getInt() or getLong() will both work just fine.

Comment: So the `mediumint` column becomes `int` through JDBC, you say?

Answer (score 0):

The type returned by the JDBC driver, if not represented as part of the JDBC specification itself (the infamous table in Appendix B), will be the smallest Java type that can represent the full range of values of the MySQL type.